# Axios FormData() getting empty Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, form-data

Browser-side code

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
data.append('userId', userId);


axios.post(`${baseUrl}/uploadFile`, data, {headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}}).then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => cb(err))
```

Server side code

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, api_key, Authorization'); 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
    next();
  }); 

app.use('/', express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I have tried almost everything but I always get an empty Object.

The file is a pdf

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `multipart/form-data` encoded data.

You have:

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

i.e.

- A decoder for URL encoded data
- A decoder for JSON encoded data

You don't have one for Multipart encoded data!

Now, since you are using it, see the documentation for [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> - busboy and connect-busboy
> - multiparty and connect-multiparty
> - formidable
> - multer